# How to build search alerts effectively?

Tags: python, node.js, database, search, triggers

I'm designing a website where a house owner can list its property for sale.

A property can be searched based on its location (city) and it's size(small/big).

I store every property listing with these attributes :

```
CREATE TABLE property (
    id int,
    name varchar(255),
    location varchar(255),
    size varchar(255),
)
```

I want to add a feature that allows the user to save search filters and receive email alerts when new properties matching their search alert are listed.

For example, a buyer A registers a search record { location: "Paris", size: "small", user_id: 1251}.

Now a seller lists a new small property for sale located in Paris.

The search alert must be triggered to send an email to buyer A.

Should I look for search alerts that match the new listing and send an email to all users affected by the alert?

How can I design design such as system ?

Note: This question is asked to figure out the architecture of the system in order to design it. But also to get feedback from developers who have already implemented a similar solution. So I hope it is in line with the stackoverflow standards.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is too broad for SO. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: my question is more elaborated than this similar question  : https://stackoverflow.com/q/6451430/9542373